# PHP iconv spits out gibberish when used on UTF-16LE

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16le

Im trying to decode UTF-16LE file to UTF-8 problem is I keep getting back kanji and I don't know what might be the cause. Code in question looks as follows

```
echo("before: ".$line);
$line = iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $line);
// $line = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16');
echo("after: ".$line);
```

where lines are read form file and tried to translate individualy, here is one such file

```
SŃSKA AZKA
asd ŹĆŻĆĄŚŃ
:61:020102C50,00NTRFNONREF//
PRZEODZĄCY
:86:010<00PRZYCHODZĄCY
<101900200001
```

when run the program
[returns this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8YkK.png)

When i replace UTF-16LE with UTF-16 output looks a little better but it's
[still wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBJvC.png)

I have no idea what might be the cause of this. I am certain file is in UTF-16LE as I just created this test file. And when I put it into online UTF-16LE decoders they come out fine.

Comment: What does `bin2hex($line)` look like? Please also include all output in text, not images.

Comment: And have you tried `$line = mb_convert_encoding($line, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE');`

Comment: @miken32 sorry for the images I didnt know how to put them here without stack trying to interpret the character codes.
this is the output of bin2hex($line)
`5300430153004b004100200041005a004b0041000d000a
006100730064002000790106017b01060104015a0143010d000a
003a00360031003a003000320030003100300032004300350030002c00300030004e005400520046004e004f004e005200450046002f002f000d000a
00500052005a0045004f0044005a000401430059000d000a
003a00380036003a003000310030003c0030003000500052005a005900430048004f0044005a000401430059000d000a
003c00310030003100390030003000320030003000300030003100`

Comment: Output of mb_convert_encoding is:

`before: SCSKA AZKA


after: SŃSKA AZKA
before: asd y{ZC

after: 愀猀搀 礀؁笁؁Ё威䌁ഁ਀
before: :61:020102C50,00NTRFNONREF//

after: 㨀㘀㄀㨀　㈀　㄀　㈀䌀㔀　Ⰰ　　一吀刀䘀一伀一刀䔀䘀⼀⼀ഀ਀
before: PRZEODZCY

after: 倀刀娀䔀伀䐀娀Ѐ䌁夀ഀ਀
before: :86:010<00PRZYCHODZCY

after: 㨀㠀㘀㨀　㄀　㰀　　倀刀娀夀䌀䠀伀䐀娀Ѐ䌁夀ഀ਀
before: <101900200001
after: 㰀㄀　㄀㤀　　㈀　　　　㄀`

Comment: You can use the edit link to add this information to your question. Use three backticks to output preformatted code, as you did with your PHP code.